# Interface Bokeh server with other javascript library

Tags: javascript, bokeh, language-interoperability

Can you interface the [bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) server with a Javascript library such as JQuery on the client side?

I want to implement an advanced form, and already have a Bokeh server app running.

However, as more and more work were being done I faced many issues with the Bokeh API, such as missing features (callbacks, options, ...), unresolved bugs, instabilities, and so on.

I came to the conclusion that it would be better that some part of the application are in Bokeh (graphs) while others, such as forms, are implemented with a more dedicated API, for example in pure Javascript.

Is this doable or even recommended? If so, how to do it?

I saw that there exists an [Ajax data source](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html#bokeh.models.sources.AjaxDataSource) in bokeh, however I'm not sure it's made for communication between the Bokeh server and a client JS page.

Any advice, explanations or examples appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can do this - I was able to make Bokeh work with input widgets created in `ClojureScript` + `re-frame`.

There're two ways to approach this:

1. Create a `ColumnDataSource` for relevant forms/inputs. In the JS code for the forms/inputs, you'll be able to query values and set new ones (don't forget to call `data_source.change.emit()` afterward)
2. Create a separate Bokeh model for relevant forms/inputs ([examples](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html)) where each field would map to a corresponding value in a form or an input. In this case, you don't need to call `emit` - you can just set values

As of now, both of this approaches have the same problem - you can't just add an arbitrary model, be it a `ColumnDataSource` or some custom model, to a Bokeh document due to [bokeh/issues/3117](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3117) and [bokeh/issues/3349](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3349), but you can create a custom model just for this:

```
from bokeh.core.properties import Instance, List
from bokeh.model import Model, DataSource


class DataSourceRoot(Model):
    sources = List(Instance(DataSource))

    __implementation__ = TypeScript("""
    import {DOMView} from "core/dom_view"
    import {Model} from "model"
    import * as p from "core/properties"

    export class DataSourceRootView extends DOMView {
        renderTo(element, replace=false): void {}
    }

    export class DataSourceRoot extends Model {
    }

    DataSourceRoot.prototype.type = 'DataSourceRoot';
    DataSourceRoot.prototype.default_view = DataSourceRootView;
    DataSourceRoot.define({
        sources: [ p.Any ]
    })
    """)
```

You'll then be able to write something like this:

```
source_root = DataSourceRoot()
curdoc().add_root(source_root)

source_root.sources.append(ColumnDataSource(id='my-source', data=dict(a=[1])))
```

And use it on JS side like this:

```
// Note the unfortunate `[0]` - right now Bokeh doesn't have a way
// to get a document by some ID
console.log(Bokeh.documents[0].get_model_by_id('my-source').data['a']);
```